# Django paginator changes pages content every iteration

Tags: python, django, paginator

I'm using Django 2.1
I'm trying to iterate over a queryset using paginator. For some reason it looks like every iteration the pages content is different.
for example on first iteration the first page contains some item, and in the next iteration, that item is now on the second page.

This is how I'm using it:

```
items_qs = Item.objects.all().filter(
        created_at__lte=on_date
    )
all_items_paginator = Paginator(items_qs, 1)
for page_number in all_items_paginator.page_range:
    page = all_items_paginator.page(page_number)
    items_ids_list = [item.id for item in page.object_list]
```

Comment: use ordering for your queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your query an explicit ordering.

```
Item.objects.order_by("created_at").filter(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that on every iteration in the 'for' loop (after I've already set the paginator) - it evaluates the  queryset again? why would it do it?